# Intercept return async call Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, reverse-proxy, interceptor

I would like some help on how to intercept the type of return of an async method in Spring, in order to signal to the user the outcome of the method.

I try to explain better technically:
inside my controller class I launch an async method

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = AppUtil.DEFAULT_ADMIN_URL + "/xxx")
@Slf4j
public class CustomController extends AbstractController {
   ...
   RequestMapping(value = "/url", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String confirm(@PathVariable(value = "key") String key, HttpServletRequest request, Locale locale, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
      ...
      Future<Long> future = methodAsync(key);
      // here I go out because the call async is very long and I do not
      // want to redeem that the reverse proxy I throw down the session
      return "redirect:/admin/another-controller";
   }
}
```

Now, I would like to be able to intercept the return of the method when it ends, and report it to the user, for example with an alert.
How could I do it? Thanks in advance

edit 1:

After view this link: https://gist.github.com/bbejeck/1387892, i use the Futures.addCallback for intercept the return type of async method, and now i would like, if it's on success, redirect on another page from Controller, in this way:

```
ListeningExecutorService pool = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10));
        ListenableFuture<Long> future = pool.submit(() -> asyncMethod(key));
        Futures.addCallback(future, new FutureCallback<Long>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Long result) {
                log.info("Complete");
                try {
 //              String urlWithSessionID = response.encodeRedirectURL("/xxx/controller/" + result);
 //              response.sendRedirect(urlWithSessionID);
                    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/xxx/controller/" + result);
                    rd.forward(request, response);
                    pool.shutdown();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log.error("Exception in sendRedirect", e);
                } catch (ServletException e) {
                    log.error("Exception in sendRedirect", e);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                log.error("Exception in task", t);
                pool.shutdown();
            }
        });
```

I try whit Redirect and Forward, but in both cases i've this exception after the info log:

16:02:00,626 ERROR [stderr] (pool-15-thread-2) Exception in thread "pool-15-thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
16:02:00,626 ERROR [stderr] (pool-15-thread-2)  at eu.sia.pda.pdaportal.web.controller.CustomController$2.onSuccess(CustomController.java:169)
16:02:00,626 ERROR [stderr] (pool-15-thread-2)  at eu.sia.pda.pdaportal.web.controller.CustomController$2.onSuccess(CustomController.java:161)
16:02:00,626 ERROR [stderr] (pool-15-thread-2)  at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:1773)
16:02:00,626 ERROR [stderr] (pool-15-thread-2)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
16:02:00,626 ERROR [stderr] (pool-15-thread-2)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
16:02:00,626 ERROR [stderr] (pool-15-thread-2)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

why??

Answer (score 1):

Please notice that if you just do:

```
Future<Long> future = methodAsync(key);
```

and then `return`
you have no way to retrieve result from your async method, as you have no reference to your `future` anymore (it will be garbage-collected)

You need to have mechanism (a back-end thread) that will be able to read the result when available from async method.

And even with separate backend thread thet 'collects' async responses you still have another issue to solve how to communicate it to the client - and to which client.

Assuming you control the client you can either force it to pool for result (on different endpoint) and display alert when such result is available, or use server push technology like for example: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications/